# still located to default data directory postgreSQL even i've changed

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7

I've fresh install postgreSQL on my centOs7 server and want to changed my default postgresql data directory to /opt/postgres on my server. and this what i have done :

```
# chown postgres:postgres /opt/postgres
# chmod 700 /opt/postgres
```

next I transfer the default data directory to the new location using the rsync command

```
# rsync -av /var/lib/pgsql/11/data /opt/postgres
```

then i remove default config file, because in another tutorial says it will be crash because postgres just listen in default folder config. [here](https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/postgresql-changing-data-directory/)

and the final way I update the data_directory variable of the /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf config file to point to the new my data directory.

```
# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

data_directory = '/opt/postgres/data'         # use data in another directory
```

Finally I start the postgresql-11 service and I see my postgres data directory still located to default data

```
[root@soa-forwarder postgres]# su - postgres
Last login: Tue Sep 29 23:48:52 WIB 2020 on pts/3
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (11.9)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show data_directory;
     data_directory
------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/11/data
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

I've been trying to restart the db but still did not changed.
do i have to re-initdb?

Comment: Did you try https://pgstef.github.io/2018/02/28/custom_pgdata_with_systemd.html

Comment: woahh its work like a charm, thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just changing `data_directory` in `postgresql.conf` won't do anything. First, the startup process has to find the directory with `postgresql.conf` in it, only then can the file be read to determine the location of the data directory.

So you will have to re-configure the startup process to look in the correct directory. In the case of the PGDG packages for CentOS, that would mean to override the service file with another one that has

```
Environment=PGDATA=/opt/postgres
```

in the `[Service]` section.